# htaccess ErrorDocument not always redirecting

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404, errordocument

I have the basic code for redirecting to a 404 custom page if a 404 not found error occurs but this does not always work as expected. I also have a rule to rewrite URLs where `page/foo/bar` is redirected to `page.php?var1=foo&var2=bar`

The rule for this is the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule .* - [L]
    RewriteRule ^page/(.*)/(.*)$ page.php?var1=$1&var2=$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

So, this works very well and I can retrieve the two variables. However, if I write in the URL bar `page/a` a error is thrown with the message `500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.` The message says the error is because of `ErrorDocument` rule. If I type a non-existent URL the `ErrorDocument` works, but in this particular case it does not.

I also want to mention that if instead of writing `page/a` I write `page/a/`, the error disappears. So the error is thrown only when I pass **one** parameter only in the URL and without a `/`.

For any other existing page, `about`, `contacts` etc.., I can easily put or remove the `/` and `.htaccess` automatically redirects me to the correct page, without the `/`

This is the code that modifies the URL removing the extension and the `/`

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Remove the slash                                                           |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Redirect to extensionless url                                              |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
    RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ $1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

And here is the code for ErrorDocument:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /boilerplate/template/404.php
```

Finally, the message in Apache error log:

```
[core:error] [pid 4400:tid 1672] [client ::1:65310] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

**EDIT**

This is the entire part about rewriting

```
# ##############################################################################
# # URL REWRITES                                                               #
# ##############################################################################
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Rewrite engine                                                             |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
  # Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /boilerplate
</IfModule>


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Remove the slash                                                           |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Redirect to extensionless url                                              |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
    RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ $1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Pretty urls                                                                |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule .* - [L]
    RewriteRule ^about/([^/]+)(?:/([^/]*))?/?$ about.php?var1=$1&var2=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**EDIT 2**

So, I deleted everything from `.htaccess` except these few rules. Nothing has changed. I cleared the cookies, emptied the cache and cleared all browser history. Also, I tried it with other browsers and the same thing happens. Just to be clear, I don't have another `.htaccess` file and the original one contains other snippets from HTML5 Boilerplate, such as caching, compressing and other non re-write related. Now I stripped the file down to these few lines.

```
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /boilerplate

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Redirect to extensionless url                                              |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
    RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ $1 [R=301,L]


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Pretty urls                                                                |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule .* - [L]
    RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)(?:/([^/]*))?/?$ page.php?var1=$1&var2=$2 [L,NC,QSA]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Can you provide your entire htaccess file?

Comment: Hi, @anubhava already answered and partially solved my problem, however here is the URL rewriting part of the htaccess. Please see the comment under anubhava answer.

Comment: Are these rules in a directory called "boilerplate"?

Comment: Yes they are, it's just a directory I use for start ups

Answer (score 1):

Replace your page rule with this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)(?:/([^/]*))?/?$ page.php?var1=$1&var2=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you, I can now write page/var1, page/var1/, page/var1/var2 and page/var1/var2/, but when I try to add another variable at the end and continue (page/var1/var2/something), I get the same 500 error. Instead I would like to either not perform any action and consider anything after the third / as part of the second variable, or simply threat it as a not found page and let ErrorDocument do its job. Can you help me ? Anyway, I thank you for the help.

Comment: Thank you for trying, but the error still persists. What does it mean the error in apache log ? I still get that error. I searched and the only solution is to add the [L] flag, but I already put the flag

Comment: Just for testing can you comment out `ErrorDocument 404` line and try again.

Comment: Ok, so commenting ErrorDocument does not change anything for this particular page. If I type a non-existing page, I get the normal 404 error, if I write page/foo/bar/foobar ( only the first two variables match rewrite rule ) I still get the same 500 error. the apache error log says the same, too many redirects. The strange thing is that ErrorDocument is commented, so I don't know why I don't get a normal 404 page

Comment: Try commenting out "slash removal" role also. It must be one of these rule conflicting. You don't have any other .htacess OR any other rule in this current .htaccess right?

Comment: Try `Options -MultiViews` at top.

Comment: That didn't work either. I guess I will leave it as it is. Thank you for all your help though.

Comment: Ok that's fine. It is something local to your setup otherwise suggested answer works well on my Apache.

Comment: The thing is I tested also on a live server and this keeps happening. Maybe is some Apache configurations, i don't know, but I'll leave it this way for the moment. Thank you again.